# java.io.IOException: Stream Closeddd

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

For reading multiple excel files, i have to create a method that returns the number of lines in this excel files, but the problem is that i open the workbook twice. Waiting for your suggestions please !!

here is the method that return the number of lines in this excel file :

```
public static  int calculateSizeFile(InputStream file)
{
    int size = 0;

    try {

        // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            if (row.getRowNum() != 0) {


                size++;
            }
            file.close();
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return size;
}
```

and here is the method that returns the list of objects in this excel file

```
    public AtlasDto[] getAtlasOperation(FileInputStream inputDuplic,int size) {
    int r = 0;
    AtlasDto[] listOperationAtlas2 = new AtlasDto[size];


    try {

        // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputDuplic);

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();



    System.out.println("la taille de atlas est :  " + r);


        String accountNumber = null;
        String ordinal = null;
        String devise = null;
        double nominal = 0;

        // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        int i = 0;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            if (row.getRowNum() != 0) {

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 4) {

                        String account = ""
                                + sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(4)
                                        .getRawValue();
                        accountNumber = account.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 9) {
                        ordinal = ""
                                + sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(9)
                                        .getRawValue();
                    }
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 7) {
                        devise = cell.getStringCellValue().toString();
                    }

                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 8) {
                        nominal = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    }

                }

                AtlasDto operationAtlas = new AtlasDto(accountNumber,
                        ordinal, devise, nominal);

                listOperationAtlas2[i] = operationAtlas;

                i++;
            }

            inputDuplic.close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return listOperationAtlas2;
}
```

and thats the exception what i am getting

```
  java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:234)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully(ZipInputStream.java:402)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:278)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:84)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)
at ma.bmci.business.dao.impl.DuplicDaoImpl.getAtlasOperation(DuplicDaoImpl.java:42)
at ma.bmci.business.service.impl.DuplicServiceImpl.getDuplicService(DuplicServiceImpl.java:24)
at ma.bmci.web.managedBeans.DuplicBean.init(DuplicBean.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:791)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1256)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in `getAtlasOperation()`, you're passing in `FileInputStream inputDuplic` and you're closing it with this:

```
inputDuplic.close();
```

after just one iteration of your `while` loop: `while (rowIterator.hasNext()) { ...`.

You have the same problem in `calculateSizeFile()`, as you've closed the file with:

```
file.close();
```

inside your `while` loop, but you're still accessing data from the workbook.

Move those lines that close the file streams after the end of your `while` loops and it should work.

Comment: @winners05: I've updated my answer -- you have the same problem with closing the file stream early in `getAtlasOperation()`.

Comment: still the same problem man , i made the .close just after the while loop

Comment: i guess that the workbook must be instantiated just once, that why the error show that the stream was closed

Comment: @winners05: The stack trace you posted clearly said that the failure happened in `getAtlasOperation()` so the only other explanation is that the `FileInputStream` is already closed by the time code execution goes into this function.

Comment: @winners05: It would also be nice to know which line in the code causes the error.